# How to get the shipping method for an order in Magento from .NET via REST API

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, magento, rest

I'm trying to pull Shipping Method from Magento Orders using the REST API from a .NET application. I don't really understand how to create the right calls and Filters. Can you help?

I was able to create a .DLL for the web service using the WSDL.exe and VBC.exe command line tools thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net). I'm now able to login and get a session ID. I see Filters, AssociativeEntity and complex_filter objects, but I'm not sure how to use them. There are examples for PHP and Perl but I've had no luck trying to interpret them into .NET

According to this doc, the shipping_method attribute is part of the SalesOrderEntity 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

Answer (score 0):

context here
https://gist.github.com/Maxhodges/8299904

"Service" object is a reference to the mageProxy object created by WSDL and explained here:
[How to call the Magento API from VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net)

```
Public Function GetShipimentMethod(ByVal orderId As String)

    Dim entity = New associativeEntity()
    entity.key = "eq"
    entity.value = orderId

    Dim complexFilter(0) As complexFilter
    complexFilter(0) = New complexFilter
    complexFilter(0).key = "increment_id"
    complexFilter(0).value = entity

    Dim filter As filters = New filters()
    filter.complex_filter = complexFilter

    Dim shipmentMethod() = _service.salesOrderList(_sessionId, filter)
    If shipmentMethod.Length > 0 Then
        Return shipmentMethod(0).shipping_description
    End If

    Return String.Format("Error: Sales Order with number {0} not found.", orderId)


End Function
```